# Using session variable to store a table with few rows and on submission of the final form , writes the data in SQLdatabase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web2py

I would like to know if it is possible to store a table with few rows in a session variable and then updating the information into a sql database on final submission in web2py .

Comment: please add your code so we can understand what you want

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? The session can store anything that can be pickled. You could, for example, store a list of dictionaries in the session and later insert them in the database.

Comment: Exactly @Anthony thats what I want to do but I am not able to. Can you show me an example or so ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
session.records = [] # Initialize the list in the session
```

Later, add a record:

```
session.records.append(dict(field1=value1, field2=value2, ...))
```

Later, insert all records into the database:

```
ids = db.mytable.bulk_insert(session.records)
```

`ids` will be a list of the `id`s of the inserted records.